# How to know if a function is non-integrable without trying to solve it?

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

so for example, this problem wanted to know if a differential equation can be solved using laplace transform. at the end there was an integral, but in the solution they simply conclude that this integral cannot be found. How exactly does one know that? In an exam i won't be having all the time in the world, so i can't just keep trying to solve it
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you list the original problem as well.

Comment: Also, Laplace transforms are used in ODEs to generate an explicit formula, then, usually, looking at a table to find the inverse of that explicit formula to obtain a solution. So in some sense, you can still use the Laplace transform; whether you obtain something useful is up to your table. In other words, look at your table, and see if you can decompose the problem using the table and properties of LT.